# How to control the behaviour of columns in a specific table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS which control the behaviour
of my favorite table:

```
#table_myfavorite1, #table_myfavorite2  {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

What I want to do is to specify the same criteria on the columns within that table (i.e. not the global one).

I tried this, but it affect the other tables.

```
#table_myfavorite1, #table_myfavorite2  td {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You should use the _Descendant selectors_. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a descendent selector. Your previous code will select all `td` in the page.

**HTML**

```
First Table
<table id="table_myfavorite1">
  <tr>
    <td>1st column</td>
    <td>2nd column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
Second Table
<table id="table_myfavorite2">
  <tr>
    <td>1st column</td>
    <td>2nd column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#table_myfavorite1 td {
  background: lightgreen;
}

#table_myfavorite2 td {
  background: tomato;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dh5y0wfa/1)

You can factorize the above code only when the property values are same, i.e. you want the same background:

```
#table_myfavorite1 td, #table_myfavorite2 td {
  background: tomato;
}
```

Comment: How do you do that if we have more than one favorite tables?

Comment: You need to use a class instead of id. `.table_myfavorite`. ID is used as unique. Class can have multiple instances.

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: I have edited the post according to your recent edit.

Comment: Yes, but only when properties and values are same.

Comment: Can give factorization example?